# Is there a way to customize stemming process in mongodb full text search?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, stemming

I have a word **"CenturyLink"** which I want to force mongodb to stem to **"Centuri"** so that when I search for **"Century"** ,which stems to **"Centuri"**, all the documents with **"CenturyLink"** are also returned.

So basically I want to add some custom set of key values of "word and it's stem" so that fts indexing is done on the basis of the provided key values.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can use `$concat` aggregation

Comment: I can't see how $concat helps here. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: put example of your collection as well

Comment: I assume when you proposed a solution you understood the context.

Comment: @Sameer no method to add custom stemming that I'm aware of. If you think this is important to your workflow, you can open a feature request in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER and post a detail of your use-case

Comment: @Sameer I cannot answer in air... you should give at least some dummy collection to get answer.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I assumed so. Thanks for the confirmation.